# Aurelia routing links generated by jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, aurelia, fancytree

Is this possible? I'm trying to add links to nodes in fancy tree, so far i've tried this:

```
let editText = this.j$('<a route-href="route:' + 'entity' + '; params.bind:{id: '+ node.key +'}"> <span style="padding: 1px 1px; font-size: 10px;">Edit</span></a>');
```

and later append that string to nodeSpan. It appears as a link on the site, but it doesn't have aurelia-generated classes (such as: 'au-target' or even 'href')

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not gonna work. The easiest solution I can imagine is generating the link using `router.generate`, like this:

```
let link = this.router.generate('routeName', { id: something });
let editText = this.j$('<a href="' + link + '"> <span style="padding: 1px 1px; font-size: 10px;">Edit</span></a>');
```

Anyway, I think you should avoid using jQuery to generate HTML. Use Aurelia features.

Comment: @Kici: I agree with Fabio Luz that you should work to not use jQuery in an Aurelia app (or most modern web apps for that matter). In any case, I created an example to show you how to do what you want to do, even though you probably shouldn't do this: https://gist.run/?id=f0fb160bdab407c97bddf7c1e7324d30

Comment: @Fabio You're right, but i didn't find any other way to do this. I'm generating links in a fancyTree method, which generates itself. Do You have anys suggestions how to use Aurelia features to do this?